# ImageButton Android with ScaleType

Tags: android, imagebutton

I tried to code this `ImageButton` dynamically in my `Activity`, but it looks very different. The **ScaleType** seems not to work. Here the `ImageButton` the way i want it:

```
     <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:src="@drawable/rot" />
```

> Here my Java-Code to generate this in my activity:

```
ImageButton field = new ImageButton(this);
                LayoutParams param = new linearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);
                field.setLayoutParams(param);
                field.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_START);
                field.setBackgroundResource(0);
                field.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                field.setImageResource(R.drawable.rot);
```

Does anyone see my mistake? Thanks!

Comment: The image source is different.  Being that you're using `WRAP_CONTENT` is may lead to it being a different size.

Comment: The image source was just an example

Comment: It doesn't change anything, when i change WRAP_CONTENT into MATCH_PARENT. He completely ignore "setScaleType".

Answer (score 0):

Set the width of the ImageButtons to fill_parent and use scaletype fitStart for the images that hug the left margin, and fitEnd for the ones on the right. Should do the trick, at least as far as your example image goes. You may have some spacing issues if the proportional width of the images exceed the screen width, but it should work for you.